# Entropy of shuffled sequence split into two groups

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, order-theory, entropy

Let it be a sequence of $N$ elements that can be ordered. At each draw, all elements from the sequence are shuffled. Example with $N = 8$:

$draw_1 = (e_4, e_3, e_0, e_6, e_1, e_7, e_2, e_5)\\
draw_2 = (e_7, e_2, e_0, e_1, e_8, e_3, e_6, e_4)\\
draw_3 = (e_4, e_0, e_3, e_2, e_6, e_5, e_7, e_1)\\
...$

Within a sequence, elements can be pairwise compared. Since there are $N!$ different orderings, each draw has an [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) of $log_2(N!)$ bits.

Now, let's modify the system such that there is two sequences of $N/2$ elements. At each draw, elements are shuffled and half of them goes to the first sequence and the other half to the second sequence. Example with $N=8$:

$
draw_1 = \{(e_4, e_3, e_7, e_0), (e_2, e_1, e_5, e_6)\}\\
draw_2 = \{(e_6, e_3, e_1, e_7), (e_5, e_0, e_2, e_4)\}\\
draw_3 = \{(e_7, e_1, e_5, e_4), (e_0, e_6, e_2, e_3)\}\\
...
$

What is the Shannon entropy of such system if the elements can only be pairwise compared between the two sequence and not within the same sequence? For example, let's define the ordering as $e_n$ < $e_{n+1}$. In $draw1$, $e_4$ is compared to $e_2$, $e_1$, $e_5$ and $e_6$; $e_3$ is compared to $e_2$, $e_1$, $e_5$ and $e_6$ etc. We can use a bit sequence to describe the draw, for example $draw_1=$1100110011110000. I am looking for the entropy of such a sequence.

The full context of this question is described in this [crypto.stackexchange question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/92063/39499).

Comment: So, order does not matter within a sequence? If we let draw${}_4=\{(e_1,e_7,e_5,e_4),(e_3,e_2,e_6,e_0)\}$, would you say draw${}_3$ is exactly the same as draw${}_4$?

Comment: @MikeEarnest I edited my answer, hopefully it is now clearer. Using binary representation, $draw_3=1111100010111011$ is different than $draw_4=0001111111011101$. But $draw_5=\{(e_7,e_1,e_4,e_5),(e_0,e_6,e_3,e_2)\}$ would be the same than $draw_3$.

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** I made a logical error, and computed the entropy assuming all microstates were equally likely. Furthermore, I think the approximations I made are a bit too crude to be useful in the range where OP is interested. I leave this answer up since it has some useful ideas, even though it is incomplete and innacurate.

---

*Answer*: The entropy of your modified draw sequence has asymptotically the same entropy as the regular draw sequence; both are $\sim \log_2 N!\sim N\log_2 N$.

Let $n=N/2$.

Each draw determines an $n\times n$ binary matrix $M$, where $M_{i,j}=1$ if the $i^{th}$ element of the first sequence is greater than the $j^{th}$ element of the second sequence, and $M_{i,j}=0$ otherwise. You want to count the number of binary matrices you can get.

Define a $2\times 2$ submatrix of $M$ to be the result of selecting two rows of $M$ (not necessarily adjacent) and two columns of $M$, and looking at the four entries of $M$ at the intersection of these rows and columns. Note that our matrix $M$ cannot have any $2\times 2$ submatrices which look like either
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad 
\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
since this would imply there were entries $a_i,a_j$ in the first sequence and $b_k,b_h$ in the second sequence for which $a_i<b_k<a_j<b_h<a_i$, a contradiction. On the other hand, you can show that *every* matrix which avoids these submatrices can be constructed from one of your draws. Therefore, counting draws is equivalent to counting matrices avoiding these submatrices.

It turns out that the number of such matrices is
$$
a_n:=\sum_{j=0}^n (j!)^2{n+1\brace j+1}^2
$$
where ${m \brace k}$ is the $(m,k)^{th}$ Stirling number of the second kind, equal to the number of ways to partition a set of size $m$ into $k$ disjoint subsets. For a proof, see the computation following Theorem 2.1 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.4884.

The sequence $a_n$ appears in https://oeis.org/A048163, and Vaclav Kotesovec claims $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n/n!)^{1/n}/n=C$, where $C=\frac1{e(\log 2)^2}\approx 0.7656928576\dots$ Therefore,
$$
\log a_n\sim \log n! +n\log n+n\log C\tag{$*$}
$$
Using Stirling's approximation, we get that
$$
\log N!\sim N \log N,
$$
while
$$
\require{cancel}
\log a_{N/2}\sim \log (N/2)! + (N/2)\log (N/2)+\cancelto{\approx 0}{\color{gray}{(N/2)\log C}}\sim N\log (N/2)\sim N \log N
$$

That is, both experiments have an asymptotic entropy of $N\log N$, so your restriction with the ordering only mattering between the two halves of the draw has negligible effect on the entropy. I am only keeping track of the dominant terms, but if necessary you can use $(*)$ to get a more precise estimate of the difference between $\log_2 N!$ and $\log_2 a_{N/2}$.

Comment: The possible outcomes in the OP's modified procedure are *not* equally-likely if $N>2$, so it seems necessary to explain why $\log_2 a_{N/2}$ should nevertheless give the entropy asymptotically. (Of course the exact entropy is the $\log_2$ of the number of possibilities only when these possibilities are equally-likely.) In other words, if $H_N$ is the exact entropy, it seems to me that there should be some argument to the effect that $H_N\sim\log_2 a_{N/2}$, and *therefore* $H_N\sim\log_2 N!$ because $\log_2 a_{N/2}\sim \log_2 N!$.

Comment: I think that @MikeEarnest solution is for [Hartley entropy (max-entropy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9nyi_entropy#Hartley_or_max-entropy). I forgot to specifically mention that I was looking for Shannon entropy. Shannon entropy is probably more difficult to estimate.

Comment: @MikeEarnest If you agree, I can update my question to specify max-entropy and create a new question for Shannon entropy so you get the bounty. I am not sure if anyone will be able to solve the Shannon entropy case.

Comment: @DurandA My answer computes Hartley entropy. I will not be able to compute Shannon entropy exactly, but I think I should be able to show it is also asymptotically $N\log N$. Am I correct that an asymptotic equivalence is sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: I would be more interested in an approximation of the Shannon entropy with $N$ in the range $[64, 2048]$. My goal is to compare the tradeoffs of different [physical unclonable function configurations](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/92063/correlations-in-ring-oscillator-pufs). Thank you for your time.

Comment: @DurandA I do not think I will be able to estimate the Shannon entropy accurately in that range.

Answer (score 4):

(This summarizes some direct enumeration computations that may supplement an analytical answer.)

Let $Y$ be the bitstring outcome of the OP's second procedure, with $N=2m$. Then $Y$ is the result of concatenating $m^2$ indicator functions as follows:
$$Y=\text{Concat}_{i=1}^m \text{Concat}_{j=m+1}^{2m}\,1_{x_i>x_j},$$
where $X=(x_1,...,x_{2m})$ is uniformly distributed on the set of $(2m)!$ permutations. (E.g., The OP's "draw1" with $m=4$ is $X=[4, 3, 7, 0, 2, 1, 5, 6] \mapsto Y=1100110011110000$.)

Now, the (Shannon) entropy of $Y$ is
$$H(Y)=-\sum_{i=1}^{a_m}p_i\log_2 p_i=-\sum_{i=1}^{a_m}{n_i\over (2m)!}\log_2 {n_i\over (2m)!}=-\sum_{j=1}^{b_m} k_j\,{r_j\over (2m)!}\log_2 {r_j\over (2m)!},\tag{1}
$$
where $a_m$ is the number of distinct elements (bitstrings) in the support of $Y$, $p_i=P(Y=i\text{th element in the support of $Y$})={n_i\over (2m)!}$ (taking the elements in some fixed order), and $n_i$ is the number of permutations mapping to the $i$th bitstring (i.e. the "multiplicity" of that bitstring).

The RHS of (1) denotes the result of summing over the $b_m$ *distinct* multiplicities $r_j$ that occur among the $n_i$, there being $k_j$ cases of $n_{i}=r_j$.

**NB**: As mentioned in another answer, the sequence $(a_m)$ is listed as [OEIS #A048163](https://oeis.org/A048163), and from comments there it can be deduced that $\log_2 a_m\sim \log_2 (2m)!$.

Following is a summary for $1\le m\le 5$, obtained by direct enumeration:

```
m  a_m     H(X)   H(Y)   Y-distribution (r_1^k_1 r_2^k_2 ... r_b^k_b)
-- -----   -----  -----  ---------------------------------------------
1  2       1      1      1^2
2  14      4.585  3.585  1^8 2^4 4^2
3  230     9.492  7.258  1^72 2^72 4^72 12^12 36^2
4  6902    15.30  11.74  1^1152 2^1728 4^2592 8^432 12^576 16^72 24^192 36^128 96^12 144^16 576^2
5  329462  21.79  16.86  1^28800 2^57600 4^115200 8^43200 12^28800 16^16200 24^21600 36^7200 48^3600 72^2400 96^1800 144^2000 288^800 576^200 1440^40 2880^20 14400^2
```

Here $r_1<r_2<\ldots<r_{b_m}$ denote the *distinct* multiplicities of the $Y$-values, and the shorthand notation $r_j\text{^}{k_j}$ indicates $k_j$ occurrences of a the *same* multiplicity $r_j$, giving the following structure for the probability distribution of $Y$ :
$$\left(\underbrace{{r_1\over(2m)!},\ldots,{r_1\over(2m)!}}_{k_1 \text{ equal probabilities}},\ \underbrace{{r_2\over(2m)!},\ldots,{r_2\over(2m)!}}_{k_2 \text{ equal probabilities}},\ \underbrace{{r_3\over(2m)!},\ldots,{r_3\over(2m)!}}_{k_3 \text{ equal probabilities}},\ldots \ldots,\ \underbrace{{r_{b_m}\over(2m)!},\ldots,{r_{b_m}\over(2m)!}}_{k_{b_m} \text{ equal probabilities}}\right).
$$

(It would be nice to have a formula for $b_m$; unfortunately, there are $46$ sequences in OEIS starting with these same first five values of $(b_m)_{m=1}^\infty=(1,3,5,11,17,\ldots)$, and it's computationally intensive to find more than the first five.)

The notation is such that $\sum_{j=1}^{b_m} k_j = |\text{support}(Y)| = a_m$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{b_m} k_j r_j = |\text{support}(X)| = (2m)!$.

E.g., for $m=2$, the multiplicity $r_1=1$ occurs $k_1=8$ times, multiplicity $r_2=2$ occurs $4$ times, and multiplicity $r_3=4$ occurs $2$ times, so the probability distribution has the structure $({1\over 4!},{1\over 4!},{1\over 4!},{1\over 4!},{1\over 4!},{1\over 4!},{1\over 4!},{1\over 4!},{2\over 4!},{2\over 4!},{2\over 4!},{2\over 4!},{4\over 4!},{4\over 4!})$, whose entropy is then found to be $3.585...$.

For this range of $1\le m\le 5$, $H(Y)\approx m\log_2(2m)$:

[image: Shannon entropy]